# Creating a field with Multiple values

Tags: mysql, field

First of all thank you for stopping by and reading this problem.
So here's my problem.
I have a table in mysql named tbl_section where the core fields should be:

- section_id
- section_name
- adviser_id
- student_id

So here's the deal is it possible for 1 section to have multiple student_id's if so how should i go about it? I've tried looking into datatype Enum to solve this dilemma but all 
i got is nothing.

Hope you guys have a solution for this. 
Thank you for reading!
The one who will solve this, I will make a statue of him and put it on my front yard like a GOD!!

Comment: Why not just have multiple rows rather than having to store and manage multiple IDs in a single field.

Comment: How about create another table with student_id being the primary key and section_id being the Foreign key ？

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need master-detail tables or 1 to N relationship tables
i.e.

```
create table section (
  section_id int,
  section_name varchar(100),
  adviser_id -- don't know what this field mean
)
create table student (
  section_id int,
  student_id int,
  student_name varchar(200)
)
```

then you may do like this

```
insert into section (1, 'section1', 0)
insert into student (1,10,'John Gordon')
insert into student (1,11,'Shor Khan')
```

then you can get all students in section1

```
select * from student where section_id = 1
```